# Проблема с выводом char в Си

Tags: char, строки, синтаксис, c++

Добрый день! При разборе указателей в Си столкунлся с одной проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char* str1 = NULL;
    str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    cin >> *str1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << str1[i];
}
```

Когда вводишь любые символы, то при выводе совпадает только первый символ строки, все остальное выводится не то, что было при вводе(бред какой-то выводится)!

Я понимаю, что можно все сделать 987654 раз проще, но я хочу разобраться именно с этим случаем.

Как сделать так, что бы вывести char строку нормально?

Comment: А откуда у Вас взялся cin в Си?

Comment: если попробовать написать тот же самый код с испольщованием printf - ничего не изменится

Comment: Как не переписывай код, в C ни `cin`, ни `cstdlib`б ни `namespace std` не появятся. Это значит, что (1) вы пользуетесь компилятором, который поддерживает и то, и другое (MSVC?), и (2) сами не знаете разницу между этими языками.

Comment: в с++ встретился с подобной проблемой только в коде использовал setlocale после того как убрал все отлично выводилось

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно разадресовывать `str1`. Когда вы передаёте в `istream::operator>>()` не указатель на `char`, а `char`, `istream` предполагает, что вы хотите прочитать только одно значение данного типа.

Доки по перегрузкам оператора `>>` в `istream`:

- [std::istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)
- [std::operator>> (istream)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/)

Comment: ну так я поэтому и вывожу все в цикле, посимвольно. 
Разве нет?

Comment: Выводите-то вы всё, а вводите только первый элемент.

Comment: Поясняю для @Hamsternik 

    cin >> *str1;

означает ввод одного символа по адресу str1[0].

Comment: @fori1ton: идеологически, для C надо использовать `scanf`, а для C++ — `readline` и `std::string`.